# Ubuntu 20.04 on HDD can not completely shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, shutdown

I have a desktop with MSI-Z690 motherboard and installed Dual boot Windows 11 on SSD and Ubuntu 20.04 on HDD.

The Windows works well. But when I power-off Ubuntu, all software quit but display still on, nothing on display but the signal is still there, and some light on black screen. The fan is still running, and I have to hold the power button for about 5 seconds to shut it down.

How to set my Ubuntu to the really normal behavior?

**Update**: according to advice of @nobody, I checked the `/var/log/syslog` and following is the log of shutdown I suppose

```
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC bluetoothd[906]: Terminating
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping GNOME Display Manager...
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash
 signatures...
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: openvpn.service: Succeeded.
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service.
Feb 22 17:16:42 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
# above should be the final lines of shutdown log. Following should be the time I power-on my PC
Feb 22 20:04:39 Litchy-PC systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
```

Update: I tried to install Ubuntu on SSD and this issue is gone.

Update: this question has moved to Ubuntu bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1964851

Comment: For how long have you waited? Sometimes a program would not stop reguarly, and the system waits for 90 seconds until it kills it. Only then, the system shuts down. Or you have some other problem preventing regular shutdown. Inspecting log files might reveal the issue.

Comment: @nobody I waited for over 5 minutes.. So I think it is just stuck.. How to see the log files?

Comment: Type `sudo less /var/log/syslog`. Then look for the time when you did your shutdown, and see if there is something indicating why the shutdown could not be done. If you are not familiar with less, you can use cursor keys, PgDn, PgUp, etc. to move through the file. Press `q` to quit/exit.

Comment: @nobody I updated the log in question.